# Is this a recommended way to use a Stored Procedure with Entity Framework 4?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

My code is doing two round trips to the database because I'm not sure if this is the correct way to create a collection of my POCO's where the first round trip hits a stored procedure because of some specific SQL code.

#### Scenario

A user enters some *AutoComplete* search query into the UI. My code hits a stored procedure (which is taking advantage of F*ull Text Search* - hence the reason I'm using a Stored Procedure) and returns all the `distinct primary keys` of the results. These go back to the code (my `IRepository class`) and I THEN use EF to retrieve all the results, for these stored procedure result.

Firstly, I don't know how to do that in `Linq to Entities` : for a collection of Id's, retrieve all the Foo entities.

Secondly, i'm doing TWO round-trips to the database. Why? Because I'm not sure how I can retrieve the rich results in the first round trip. The entity consists of a few `POCO` classes and has two `ICollection` properties also, etc...

**Is this the correct way I should be using a stored procedure and then retrieving the rich, populated entities.**

I'll quickly create a dummy class diagram to help with any answers.

```
public class Person
{
    string Name;
    int Age;
    ICollection<string> NickNames;
    ICollection<Foo> DonnoSomethingElses;
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the two roundtrips sound like an avoidable problem - couldn't you do something like:

```
WITH FullTextResults AS
(
   SELECT ID, ...... --- do your full text search here
)
SELECT
   (list of fields) 
FROM
   dbo.YourDataTable t
INNER JOIN
   FullTextResults ftr ON t.ID = ftr.ID  -- join on primary key
WHERE
   .....  -- possibly limit results
```

and just return the output of this CTE (Common Table Expression) from your stored proc?? That would then return a data set with rows and columns from your actual data table, and EF could materialize your `Person` classes from that.....

Comment: L what about the fact that the person poco has 2x ICollections? These collections need to be populated also?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: those might require additional roundtrips, to populate, if needed. Unfortunately, EF currently doesn't seem to support stored procedures returning more than one result set in a single call

Comment: cheers. that's what i was afraid of -> EF support for a single recordset only. This is why I'm going to need to do 2 round trips. In your example above, I don't need to do the CTE because EF will generate the full, rich (and probably large) sql statement to populate the poco and all it's children (read: ICollections) which i've asked to `Include`. Just not sure how to do that in Linq ... Get all Poco's which have an ID that exists in this Id collection...